# CSS not work after ajax replace

Tags: ajax

I  have found that when I replace forms with AJAX, then the new forms loose their display styling. It seems like the css for the forms are not working any more.

How to solve this issue?
Do i have to write js bind with .on() function to add css again? Any other suggesions?

Answer (score 2):

In some cases it can depend on how and where you have added your CSS to the page.

The best way to do it is using [#attached](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attached) on your field via [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or similar.

If your CSS is already on the page though it should work on new elements added with ajax.

One possible cause is that your CSS selectors are too specific and the ID/class used isn't matching properly with the markup added by the ajax.

Comment: Yes, ID tags in a reloaded form will be different from what was there before. It's bad practice to identify form elements by ID in CSS for this very reason.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, any event handlers that were attached will be disconnected when content is replaced by AJAX. You can use jQuery's .[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) as alternative event hooks to prevent this.